# Adding a field with Groovy AST doesn't generate getter and setter

Tags: groovy, field, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

So I'm writing an AST Transformation that adds a field with the @Delegate annotation to a class

```
@SimpleAST
class PersonBuilder{
}
```

Should produce

```
class PersonBuilder{
        @Delegate
        Person target = new Person
    }
```

My Interface:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass("poc.SimpleASTTransformation")
public @interface SimpleAST {

    /**
     * A class for which builder methods should be created. It will be an error to leave
     * this attribute with its default value for some strategies.
     */

    Class value()

}
```

My transformation:

```
@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class SimpleASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    @Override
    void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit source) {

        ClassNode classNode = (ClassNode) astNodes[1]

        if (!astNodes) return
        if (!astNodes[0]) return
        if (!astNodes[1]) return
        if (!(astNodes[0] instanceof AnnotationNode)) return
        if (!(astNodes[1] instanceof ClassNode)) return

        println "Running AST Transformation for ${classNode.getNameWithoutPackage()}..."

        AnnotationNode annotationNode = (AnnotationNode) astNodes[0]
        ClassExpression classExpression = (ClassExpression) annotationNode.getMember("value")
        String packageName = classNode.getPackageName()
        String builderClassNameWithoutPackage = classNode.getNameWithoutPackage()
        String originalClassNameWithPackage = classExpression.getText()
        originalClassNameWithPackage = Validate.checkOriginalClassName(originalClassNameWithPackage)
        Class<?> originalClass = Class.forName(originalClassNameWithPackage)
        ClassNode originalClassNode = new ClassNode(originalClass)
        String originalClassNameWithoutPackage = originalClassNode.getNameWithoutPackage()

        println "Generating methods for $originalClassNameWithoutPackage..."

        generateTargetField(classNode,originalClass)

        println "Transformation applied!"

    }

   static void generateTargetField(ClassNode classNode, Class originalClass){
        ClassNode originalClassNode = new ClassNode(originalClass)
        ConstructorCallExpression constructorCallExpression = new ConstructorCallExpression(originalClassNode,new ArgumentListExpression())
        FieldNode fieldNode = new FieldNode("target",
                2,
                originalClassNode,
                classNode,
                constructorCallExpression)

        ArrayList<AnnotationNode> annotationNodes = new ArrayList<>()
        annotationNodes.add(new AnnotationNode(new ClassNode(Delegate)))
        fieldNode.addAnnotations(annotationNodes)
        classNode.addField(fieldNode)
    }
}
```

When I check the byte code there is no getter/setter methods for the fields inside the Class Person (I used @Delegate on the target field)

However, if I Just add the field manually and compile the code I get getter and setters for the fields in class Person.

Person has 2 fields: firstName, lastName both Strings.

Comment: Isn't `@Delegate` a compile-time annotation? You're generating a .class file, right? Not source? So there's no compilation?

Comment: You're right, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Create the getter/setter pair yourself?